# How to write this more cleanly in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, lambda

I know there has got to be a cleaner more elegant way to do this. I have an array of number in the range [0,1] and want to check which ones are greater than a threshold. I remember there being some syntax to do this nicely. In python I would use something like a lambda function.

```
p = sigmoid(dot(theta,X));
for i =1:size(p)
   if(p(i)>=0.5)
      p(i)=1
   else
       p(i)=0
   end
end
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

mtrw is on the right track, but it gets even shorter:

```
p = (p >= 0.5);
```

Comment: I feel dumb. +1. In regular Python, you'd probably do `[int(k >= 0.5) for k in p]`.

Comment: In fact, since the OP is overwriting `p` anyway, he might as well avoid the cost of the sigmoid call and just do `p = dot(theta,X) >= 0.0;`

Answer (score 4):

You can simply say `p = (p>=0.5)`. Boolean operators work on arrays, and return logical arrays (which consist of boolean values).

Answer (score 2):

You can operate on the whole array at once:

```
p(p >= 0.5) = 1;
p(p < 0.5) = 0;
```

For what it's worth, you can do the same thing in Numpy if `p` is a Numpy array:

```
>>> p[p >= 0.5] = 1
>>> p[p < 0.5] = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for variety. You can also do:

```
p = floor(p + 0.5);
```

which also generalises to other thresholds in the range [0,1].